# Pushing a new object into an array causes it to duplicate

Tags: typescript

I'm currently have an array as follows:

```
let arr = [{ foo: "bar", number: 1 }, { foo: "bar1", number: 2 }, { foo: "bar2", number: 3 }]
```

I want to ensure that there are no duplicates in the array, so I have the following function:

```
function test(foo) {
    let i = { foo, number: 1 };
    for (let t = 0; t < this.arr.length; t++) {
        if (this.arr[t].foo === foo) {
            this.arr[t].number += 1;
            break;
        } else {
            this.arr.push(i);
            break
        }
    }
}
```

If I do `test(bar)`, `bar` will have it's value successfully increment to 2.

`[{ foo: "bar", number: 2 }, { foo: "bar1", number: 2 }, { foo: "bar2", number: 3 }]`

However, if I do `test(bar1)`, the value of `bar1` does not increment. Instead a new object

`{foo: "bar1", number: 1}`  is pushed into the array. This causes the array to become

`[{ foo: "bar", number: 2 }, { foo: "bar1", number: 2 }, { foo: "bar2", number: 3 }, {foo: "bar1", number: 1}]`

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting aside the fact that the above does not compile cleanly (what is `this`), the issue is just that you are never checking any element of `arr` past the first one.  Instead of letting `t` go to `1`, you're instead pushing the new object onto the array and `break`ing the loop.  I'm guessing you'd rather do something like this:

```
function test(foo: string) {
  let i = { foo, number: 1 };
  for (let t = 0; t < arr.length; t++) {
    if (arr[t].foo === foo) {
      arr[t].number += 1;
      return; // not just break, but return from the function here
              // if you need to break instead you need more logic here
    }
  }
  // if you made it here you've gone through the whole loop and haven't found a match
  arr.push(i); 
}
```

That should at least work the way you were expecting.  Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!